# Preciso de ajuda para criar um bat para enviar arquivo do SAPLOGON.ini

Tags: batch

Preciso de ajuda para criar um bat para enviar arquivo do SAPLOGON.ini
para todos os usuários, com perfil criado no computador.

Esse é meu codigo bat, preciso de ajudar quero enviar pra todos usuários, de uma unica vez.

veja abaixo:

```
@ECHO Copia Config SAP LOGON Padrão.


xcopy "\\meuservidor\SAP\SAPLOGON.INI" C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\SAP\Common /Y
```

Só funciona para o usuário que está logado, já para outro usuário com perfil criado não funciona, preciso de ajuda, pra este bat funcionar e enviar para todos usuários com perfil no computador.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se for usar o comando para **Windows 7 ou superior**:

```
cd C:\Users

dir /b > Users.txt

for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (Users.txt) do (
    if exist "C:\Users\%%A\AppData\Roaming\SAP\Common" (
        xcopy "\\meuservidor\SAP\SAPLOGON.INI" "C:\Users\%%A\AppData\Roaming\SAP\Common" /Y
    )
    else (
        echo Pasta "C:\Users\%%A\AppData\Roaming\SAP\Common" nao existe!
    )
)

pause
```

Se for **Windows XP** substituir `C:\Users` por `C:\Documents and Settings`

> Provavelmente terá que executar como Administrador.

Comment: Perfeito, voce salvou  minha vida...lol...

Comment: Avalia a resposta então, setinha pra cima!